# IntelliJ IDEA: StackOverflowError on Build Project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using the following IntelliJ.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 EAP
Build #IU-172.2953.9, built on June 14, 2017
IntelliJ IDEA EAP User
Expiration date: July 14, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b3 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.5
```

I have been getting **java.lang.StackOverflowError** upon building the project.

Has anyone fallen into the same situation?

Build Message↓

```
Information:java: The system is out of resources.
Information:java: Consult the following stack trace for details.
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$13.visitClassType(Types.java:1955)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:786)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$DefaultTypeVisitor.visit(Types.java:4571)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.asSuper(Types.java:1952)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.unboxedType(Types.java:3987)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.unboxedTypeOrType(Types.java:3998)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$ArgumentExpressionKind.standaloneKind(DeferredAttr.java:1135)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredChecker.visitLiteral(DeferredAttr.java:1296)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCLiteral.accept(JCTree.java:2037)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$FilterScanner.scan(DeferredAttr.java:913)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr.isDeferred(DeferredAttr.java:1100)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribArgs(Attr.java:669)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1815)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:575)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3249)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
Information:java:   at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1824)
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'webapi'
Information:javac 1.8.0_101 was used to compile java sources
Information:2017/06/21 21:22 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 49 warnings in 24s 170ms
Error:java: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Comment: Check your Workspace for the '.meatadata/.log', maybe you will find a hint there

Comment: Post the full exception stack trace.

Comment: @CrazyCoder That is all I got.

Comment: Try adding `-Xss4m` [here](http://i.imgur.com/RjanpuY.png).

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank you! It worked!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Adding `-Xss4m` to the build process VM options should help:

[image: vm options]

Comment: 2019 and that amount of memory is still enough :)

Comment: I tried this but it was not working even when i increased that memory to 8192m. So turns out that i was missing adding it in File → settings → Build,Execution,Deployment → Build Tools → Maven → Runner VM Options,  as already mentioned in one of the answer below.

Comment: You have to be kidding me that this issue persists in 2024... Anyway, thanks a lot. This solved my problem!

Answer (score 5):

I also met the same problem. I finally fixed it following thes steps:

In IDEA:

1. File → settings → Build,Execution,Deployment → Build Tools → Maven → Runner
   VM Options: add `-Xss4096k`
2. File → settings → Build,Execution,Deployment → Compiler
   Shared build process VM options: add `-Xss4m`

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting the issue in Run/Debug configuration, you can change the same in Run->Edit Configurations->VM parameters:
-Xms512M -Xmx1024M **-Xss4M** -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled

[image]