# Intellij IDEA: StackOverflowError on building project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, build, stack-overflow

I have a `StackOverflowError` when building the project in Intellij IDEA 2017.2. It started ocurring after I dropped all IDEA settings and started onboarding my project again.

The build log has the following:

```
2017-12-13 14:59:55,043 [  16299]   INFO - .incremental.IncProjectBuilder - Building project; isRebuild:false; isMake:true parallel compilation:false
2017-12-13 14:59:55,043 [  16299]   INFO - kotlin.jps.build.KotlinBuilder - is Kotlin incremental compilation enabled: true
2017-12-13 14:59:55,043 [  16299]   INFO - kotlin.jps.build.KotlinBuilder - is Kotlin experimental incremental compilation enabled: true
2017-12-13 14:59:55,060 [  16316]   INFO - kotlin.jps.build.KotlinBuilder - is Kotlin compiler daemon enabled: true
2017-12-13 14:59:55,060 [  16316]   INFO - kotlin.jps.build.KotlinBuilder - Label in local history: build started 2019016a
2017-12-13 14:59:55,066 [  16322]   INFO - CompilerBackwardReferenceIndex - backward reference index version differ due to: class java.io.FileNotFoundException
2017-12-13 14:59:55,080 [  16336]   INFO - .incremental.IncProjectBuilder - Cleaned output directories in 14 ms
2017-12-13 14:59:55,346 [  16602]   INFO - .incremental.IncProjectBuilder - maven-resources-test:project-common: java.lang.StackOverflowError
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.ProjectBuildException: maven-resources-test:project-common: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1035)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:900)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:733)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:385)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:192)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:295)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:236)
at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.getByteBuffer(PagedFileStorage.java:193)
at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree$BtreePage.syncWithStore(IntToIntBtree.java:332)
at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree$BtreePage.setAddress(IntToIntBtree.java:321)
at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree.processLeafPages(IntToIntBtree.java:1178)
at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree.processLeafPages(IntToIntBtree.java:1179)
at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree.processLeafPages(IntToIntBtree.java:1179)
at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree.processLeafPages(IntToIntBtree.java:1179)
```

And many many more same invocations of this method. At the end of stacktrace:

```
2017-12-13 14:59:56,059 [      0]   INFO - etbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain - Build process started. Classpath: C:/path/to/idea/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/path/to/jdk/lib/tools.jar;C:/path/to/idea/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar
2017-12-13 14:59:56,150 [     91]   INFO - til.internal.PlatformDependent - Your platform does not provide complete low-level API for accessing direct buffers reliably. Unless explicitly requested, heap buffer will always be preferred to avoid potential system instability.
2017-12-13 14:59:56,528 [    469]   INFO - etbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain - Connection to IDE established in 439 ms
2017-12-13 14:59:56,544 [    485]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational
2017-12-13 14:59:56,545 [    486]   INFO - jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Loading model: project path = /path/to/project, global options path = path/to/options
2017-12-13 14:59:57,128 [   1069]   INFO - jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Model loaded in 583 ms
2017-12-13 14:59:57,128 [   1069]   INFO - jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Project has 11 modules, 179 libraries
2017-12-13 14:59:57,316 [   1257]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=500; buffer=10; max=3536
2017-12-13 14:59:57,512 [   1453]   INFO - etbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain - Pre-loaded process ready in 1453 ms
```

I have found a similar question -  [IntelliJ IDEA: StackOverflowError on Build Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675448/intellij-idea-stackoverflowerror-on-build-project) , but the solution there - setting `-Xss4m` did not help me.

I think this error might be in some way connected with my `settings.xml` Maven file because I modified it after clearing IDEA's settings. However, I cannot understand why it leads to this error.

I would very much appreciate any help on the subject.

Comment: Do you face the same issue with new projects without maven? Does it help if you switch to the default settings.xml?

Comment: @y.bedrov Switching to default settings.xml leads to the same issue with this project. However, current settings.xml and brand new maven project work fine together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution (a pretty straightforward one) was to completely reinstall IDEA with dropping all the configurations and plugins. Reinstalling IDEA while keeping configuration hadn't worked before, so most likely I had some misconfiguration in its settings files.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem after loading and unloading modules repeatedly. Changing the stack size didn't help, and the build worked from the command line with Maven.

I did File->Invalidate Caches / Restart... and that fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing this but it didn't help. The solution that helped me was only to completely reinstall IDEA as described in accepted answer.

Comment: I did that, + reimport all maven projects, and it worked for me. I had the error message in the IntelliJ build output, but not in `/Users/(myuser)/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea2018.2`.