# Intellij IDEA StackOverflow error when building project

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm working with Intellij IDEA Community Edition, having a maven project with 6 modules and 122 classes in total.
When I'm trying to run the main class from one of the sub-modules, IDEA first builds the project and this is when I get the StackOverflowError message. Of course it happens when I just build the project.

It looks like this:

`Information:javac 1.8.0_25 was used to compile java sources
Information:09/08/2018 14:44 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 1 warning in 5 s 57 ms
Error:java: java.lang.StackOverflowError`

IDEA version is: 2018.1.6

I tried reinstalling the same version and installing a previous version 2016.x.x (don't remember exactly). Also tried the solution with -Xss4m suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675448/intellij-idea-stackoverflowerror-on-build-project)  , but with no success. I don't have this problem on other similar projects (maven with modules).

Does anyone know why this could happen or how can I investigate the problem?

Might it be related to lombok (I'm using the lombok plugin in IDEA)?

**UPDATE**:

I add the build logs below:

```

```
2018-08-09 15:00:10,503 [ 116169]   INFO - .incremental.IncProjectBuilder - Building project; isRebuild:false; isMake:true parallel compilation:false
2018-08-09 15:00:10,573 [ 116239]   INFO - .incremental.IncProjectBuilder - Cleaned output directories in 6 ms
2018-08-09 15:00:10,731 [ 116397]   INFO - s.incremental.java.JavaBuilder - Compiling 24 java files; module: PROJECT_XXX_MODULE1
2018-08-09 15:00:13,261 [ 118927]   INFO - s.incremental.java.JavaBuilder - java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:553)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:198)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:453)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:317)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:244)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:202)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1314)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:991)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1063)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:954)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:787)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:376)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:183)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:308)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:235)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$$Lambda$26/31644974.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$$Lambda$8/7438855.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$UnaryVisitor.visit(Types.java:4532)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.supertype(Types.java:2295)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$13.visitClassType(Types.java:1956)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$13.visitClassType(Types.java:1945)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:778)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$DefaultTypeVisitor.visit(Types.java:4451)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.asSuper(Types.java:1942)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$13.visitClassType(Types.java:1958)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$13.visitClassType(Types.java:1945)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:778)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$DefaultTypeVisitor.visit(Types.java:4451)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.asSuper(Types.java:1942)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$13.visitClassType(Types.java:1965)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$13.visitClassType(Types.java:1945)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:778)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$DefaultTypeVisitor.visit(Types.java:4451)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.asSuper(Types.java:1942)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$4.visitClassType(Types.java:918)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$4.visitClassType(Types.java:841)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:778)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$DefaultTypeVisitor.visit(Types.java:4451)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.isSubtype(Types.java:837)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.isSubtype(Types.java:801)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.isSubtypeUncheckedInternal(Types.java:754)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.isSubtypeUnchecked(Types.java:738)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.isConvertible(Types.java:296)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.isAssignable(Types.java:2154)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.isAssignable(Types.java:2115)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.model.JavacTypes.isAssignable(JavacTypes.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.TypeUtils.isCollectionOrMap(TypeUtils.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processSimpleTypes(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:221)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processTypeElement(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:201)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processNestedType(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processNestedTypes(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:286)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processTypeElement(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:203)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processNestedType(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processNestedTypes(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:286)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processTypeElement(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:203)
    [............almost 1000 of the same calls looping between them......]
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processNestedType(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processNestedTypes(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:286)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processTypeElement(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:203)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processNestedType(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processNestedTypes(ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.java:286)
2018-08-09 15:00:13,287 [ 118953]   INFO - brains.jps.incremental.Builder - Dependency analysis found 0 affected files
2018-08-09 15:00:13,289 [ 118955]   INFO - s.incremental.java.JavaBuilder - javac 1.8.0_25 was used to compile [PROJECT_XXX_MODULE1]
2018-08-09 15:00:13,972 [      0]   INFO - etbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain - ==================================================
2018-08-09 15:00:13,973 [      1]   INFO - etbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain - Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.6/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/jdk/jdk1.8.0_25-windows-i586/lib/tools.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.1.6/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar
2018-08-09 15:00:14,351 [    379]   INFO - etbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain - Connection to IDE established in 348 ms
2018-08-09 15:00:14,370 [    398]   INFO - penapi.util.io.win32.IdeaWin32 - Native filesystem for Windows is operational
2018-08-09 15:00:14,415 [    443]   INFO - jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Loading model: project path = C:/PROJECT_XXX, global options path = C:/Users/me/.IdeaIC2018.1/config/options
2018-08-09 15:00:14,828 [    856]   INFO - jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Model loaded in 413 ms
2018-08-09 15:00:14,829 [    857]   INFO - jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl - Project has 6 modules, 176 libraries
2018-08-09 15:00:14,970 [    998]   INFO - ellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage - lower=100; upper=200; buffer=10; max=656
2018-08-09 15:00:15,223 [   1251]   INFO - etbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain - Pre-loaded process ready in 1252 ms
```

```

Update 2: As suggested by Wiciaq123 I set Xmx to 4G but didn't change the behaviour. My vm options are:

```
# custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options

-Xms512m
-Xmx4096m
-Xss512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

Comment: Bumping up heap size will not help you as the problem is obviously related to stack being overflown (as an exception says). Which version of Spring Boot do you use?

Comment: Please show us your classes annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`

Comment: Try using a more recent JDK build. _25 is way too ancient and may have bugs. `-Xmx` will not help here, stack size can be adjusted with `-Xss` option. Try `-Xss4m`.

Comment: Maciej Dobrowolski thanks for the suggestion. I managed to fix the problem after I revised my @ConfigurationProperties classes; it's odd nonetheless